# Caching page with user interaction in zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-cache

I need to cache a page (**a user page** ) and this page contain a follow button for logged in members and comments block.

How to cache this page ?

**Suggestion 1 :** 
 the page is cached until an action happens in the page then delete the current cache ?
 Does this Solution cause a high I/O Performance on the server

**or there ** is another way ?

Comment: Why do you need to cache the page? Queries, construction, ...?

Comment: @lorey I need to cache whole page, file cache. do I have to split the page into boxes and cache the boxes ?

Comment: My question was why do you need to cache the page since this is important to answer your question right. You have to give more details on database access or performance intensive operations going on to get a good way to cache as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on which storage adapter you want to use and other implementation details. Since you're asking an unspecific question, I can only answer unspecifically:

I wildly guess that your queries are expensive and you therefore should cache them in the first place. An example on how to do this can be found here: http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/zend-framework-2-using-zendcache-and-hydratingresultset-to-save-database-resultset/

Altough I wouldn't recommend to do it in your (guessed) case, you can find out more about caching a whole site here: [How to approach caching in ZF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765088/how-to-approach-caching-in-zf2)

**More about n genral`Zend\Cache`**

Quick start:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.cache.storage.adapter.html#quick-start

Examples on how to use `Zend\Cache` can be found here:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.cache.storage.adapter.html#examples